# Where is MonoDevelop.Macinterop reside?

Tags: interop, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I see some classess I would Like to use here 
https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop

But I cannot find the dll where the namespace MonoDevelop.Macinterop resides in??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's in MacPlatform.dll

Since that dll depends on several other large MonoDevelop dlls, I would recommend you copy the code you need into your own project.